# FB PHP SDK know if user liked my tab page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying to find out if the user likes my Fan Page (I have installed an FB App as a Tab inside) the page,

I have searched online and found this code which is supposed to work:

```
        $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($signed_request);
        echo "</pre>";
        $liked = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
```

and this is the data I am getting, but I cannot know if the user is liking the page or not:

Array

```
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [code] => AQA7PQo8FBLaHlEe3IgYMBg_4Smwt_qsgWpiUnnG2XIco0ndK3zcCMgK4M7975cr1oUmL2iYv5UhBKM-hAxOmUUwbhuj2ZHfMiLNeO8ZBc4c5jexI-VZuDGFwnnW4-eg433gVbDo_uLQ8MBpjI2kT8c6B_VvNLoY4_Oel5odc6tObW54a0Thdd7a_Bhq-kHOHz-CJxgBOWLDGR9plUhgZGs9o34jHfOZLFRGOQvSxd1PcFkuMorKy2lP9AHnBdZ2BI8wsy_U_TGbPPt2uGdS5nkpvJbfvh5JPT8zULAm_nWBtZ4YfZcngSj64KZDvr8Fwr0
    [issued_at] => 1374161190
    [user_id] => ----
)
```

what am I missing ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have captured the signed request, you need to perform three steps:

1. Split the signed request into two parts delineated by a `.` character (eg. `238fsdfsd.oijdoifjsidf899`).
2. Decode the first part — the encoded signature — from base64url.
3. Decode the second part — the 'payload' — from base64url and then decode the resulting JSON object.

Here's a function that does all this:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];  

function parsePageSignedRequest() {  
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {  
        $sig = null;  
        $payload = null;  
        list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);  
        $sig = base64_decode(strtr($sig, '-_', '+/'));  
        $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));  
        return $data;  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

Usage:

```
if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {  
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {  
        echo "User liked the page";
    } 
    else {  
        echo "User haven't liked your page (yet)";
    }  
}
```

Documentation: [Signed Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/), [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/base64_decode), [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: thanks...that worked perfect, but in the PHP SDK , the getSignedRequest() function I was using does the exact thing...
weirdly enough, when I ran the same original script I had in the beginning, I got all the data I needed (which was also exactly equal to the data I got from your script);....

any idea why last time I tested this code, I didn't get all the data, but now I did (keeping the same code)

Comment: It happens sometimes. :)

Comment: oh ok...so it's just random ? :p no work around or something ?

Comment: @Monk: That was actually not a typo :)

Comment: You sure about that? :) if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {

Comment: @Monk: yes. It assigns the return value of the function call `parsePageSignedRequest()` to the variable `$signed_request`. The statements inside the `if` block are only evaluated if `parsePageSignedRequest()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has removed the liked page property of the signed_request object for Page Tab apps on November 5th 2014. That's sad news.